# iOS layer.borderWidth

Tags: ios, uiview, layer

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-8, -10, 20, 20)];
image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample"];
[view addSubview:image];
```

image is on the view, but the border line is transparent・・・
Please give me how to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by “the border line is transparent”?  Do you mean the image overlays it?

Comment: Do you need the border to be transparent or not ?

Comment: YES.
image overlays it,but the view.layer.borderWidth is visible...

Comment: Once check with line I have posted

Comment: for imageview the frame is like (-8, -10, 20, 20). Can I now why it?

Comment: I want to explain by using image.
but, I do not have 10 reputation, I can not add Image...

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
image.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Add the above line of code.Issue will be resolved.

Comment: Once try with different contentmodes